# Setting a variable when user selects from a dropdown

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

In my rails view, I have a dropdown menu of patients. When a user selects a patient, I want to set @patient to be Patient.find(id)  where id a data attribute on the item the user selected.

How can I achieve this?

Action:

```
 def options
    @assessment = current_user.assessments.new
    @patients = current_user.patients.sort_by{|e| e.first_name.downcase}
    @patient = current_user.patients.new
    @templates = Template.all
  end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @assessment, :method=>"get", :url => url_for(:action => 'new') do |f| %>

    <%= f.select :patient_id, content_tag(:option,'select patient...',:value=>"")+content_tag(:option,'New Patient',:value=>"")+options_from_collection_for_select(@patients, 'id', 'full_name'), :class=>"form-control" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <div class="row" id="assessment-type" style="display:none;">


    // WANT TO SET @patient HERE TO WHATEVER THE USER SELECTED IN ABOVE SELECT TAG //


    <% if @patient.has_past_assessments? %>
      <%= link_to "New Injury", templates_path, :id=>"new-injury", :remote=> true %> or <%= link_to "Followup Assessment", "#" %>
    <% end %>


  <%= f.hidden_field :template_id %>


<% end %>

</div>

<script>

  $(function(){
    $('#assessment_patient_id').chosen({width: "100%"});
  });

  $('#assessment_patient_id').change(function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("assessment_patient_id");
    var patient_id = (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)

    if (patient_id == 0) {
      window.location.href = "/patients/new"
    } else {
      $('#assessment-type').slideDown(350);
    }

    $('#assessment-type').find('.template').on('click', function(){
      startSpinner()
      var templateId = parseInt($(this).find('a').attr("id"));
      $('#assessment-type').find('.template').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $('#assessment_template_id').val(templateId);
      $('.new_assessment').submit();
    });


  });


 </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you want to set a ruby variable from the html when you change the select value? I don't see how you can do that without send a request to a action. what do you want to achieved?

Comment: It doesn't work like that @Jackson.  Variables like `@patient` are class instance variables which are used to pass data from your controller to your view.  From the view, once a form is submitted, the `params` hash gets populated and is available for the controller post action to process.

Comment: Could I use JQuery to do an Ajax call when there is a change to the f.select?  And then set @patient to patient.find(params[:id])